# download sql server can't connect to server

Tags: sql-server

I downloaded SQLServer and now I'm trying to connect to the server and a got a note that says: could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal- What is wrong

[image: Error-Description]

Comment: I don't think SQL Express supports SSAS

Comment: No need to find about it, @holder. It does not: [Analysis Services features supported by SQL Server editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017). :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Express does not support SSAS. Try installing the Developer edition of SQL Server instead which is free of charge but cannot be used in a production environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017